# Question about calculating Average in PHP

Tags: php, average

I am a newbie learning PHP and i am trying to find average of 3 numbers but not getting the correct answer. I don't know where i am going wrong.

```
function percentage($math,$eng,$sc){

     $s = $math+$eng+$sc / 3 ;
     
     return $s;
     
   }

  $p = percentage(10,20,30);
  
  echo $p;
```

I am getting the ansewer as 40 whereas i am supposed to get 20. Kindly check if there is any error.

Comment: Hint: `$s = ($math + $eng + $sc) / 3;`.

Comment: you missed bracket

Comment: why do you call your function `percentage()` and not `average()`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate..@zohorov & @Nikita for prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Return value is right. Check operators precedence.

If you want 20 as return value code is:

```
$s = ($math+$eng+$sc) / 3 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use parentheses:

```
$s = ($math+$eng+$sc) / 3 ;
```

All things together:

```
function percentage($math,$eng,$sc){
  $s = ($math+$eng+$sc) / 3 ; 
  return $s; 
}

echo percentage(10,20,30);
```